# redirect SSL subdomain to non SSL subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I'm completely lost as I've tried a variety of ways to get this accomplished, but nothing seems to work.

All I want to do is get the following setup:

FROM: https://sites.example.com
TO: http://sites.example.com

NOTE: same "sites" subdomain, except I do not want the subdomain "sites" to have https://

I also do want to keep my SSL for all other areas except the "sites" subdomain.

Thanks in advance,
JR

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sites\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks! Will this work for different URLs?  

Examples: 

https://sites.example.com/test1/test_4.aspx?ci=1234&cid_id=111&pl_id=1234

https://sites.example.com/test22/abc123/acme.aspx?ci=1784&prog_id=1444

Thanks

Comment: Yes as long as it is `https://` and domain starts with `sites` this will work for all the URLs.

Comment: Hi again,

I tried it and unfortunately, it's not working.

Is there a more direct way to do this?  

In other words, can I put the URL itself instead of http_host?

Comment: You can but that won't solve it. What is location of this .htaccess and are there more rules?

Comment: Hi

/public_html/.htaccess

There are no other RewriteEngine rules except yours:

# Use PHP 5.3
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php 

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sites\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

It's a Joomla Site, so not sure if that matters.

There's also this:
# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

Comment: Just make sure this is first rule.

Comment: Hi anubhava, I think that did it!  I put it at the very beginning and it seems to be working fine now.  I'm very grateful for your help.  Thanks so much! :)

Comment: I spoke too soon :(

It's only directing to the http://sites.example.com and NOT the entire URL.

This example URL 
https://sites.example.com/test1/search.aspx?ci=1234&cid_id=1234

Should direct to:
http://sites.example.com/test1/search.aspx?ci=1234&cid_id=1234

But it's only redirecting to
http://sites.example.com/

Comment: It does redirect whole URL if this is very first rule.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, but that's not working.  Not sure why this is happening.